# how to open a web site for offer my service like freelancer in internet?

Tags: freelance-websites

Hello everyone I am new how to freelancer and I would like to be start my own website where I  offer my own server (make website,videogames,server,docker,copywriting,etc)

do you think is good idea open a website like freelancer (no a company)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as your webpage making skills are up there.

Websites can be static, meaning you won't need to keep maintaining them, but also allow potential clients to see the kind of work you can do for them. It turns into your portfolio, and you simply update it when you have new projects you're allowed to share.

Hosting is dirt cheap - I pay under $15 CAD per year for a `.ca` domain, and other country-specific domains are usually low. If you have your own server, you can host it yourself - if not, you can pay $5 USD/mo for a Digital Ocean droplet (or the like).

The best part is that you can simply refer potential clients to your website if they want to see what kind of work you can offer them, freeing you up to deal with actual work that comes your way.